# Can't Uninstall LibreOffice5.3 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: libreoffice, software-uninstall

So I somehow installed LibreOffice 5.3, but only Impress. Now I am unable to remove Impress. I also have LibreOffice 5.0 installed, and would like to keep that version of Impress and not Impress 5.3. Software Center doesn not uninstall Impress 5.3 for some reason.

Even when I uninstall the entire LibreOffice, Libre Impress 5.3 does not get removed.

How can I uninstall Impress 5.3?

Comment: What is the output of `dpkg --list libreoffice-impress`?

Comment: @ubashu [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/76uTV)

Comment: Did you use the "snap" installation method perhaps?

Comment: yes, I did @Rinzwind

Comment: try my answer ;-) snap does not use apt..

Comment: Please don't add "Solved" to the title. See https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/7413/15003.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove software installed with "snap" use

```
sudo snap remove {package_name}
```

Libreoffice would be ...

```
sudo snap remove libreoffice
```

I did not find a snap for Impress itself so start with that one 1st.